# Odoo 8 : what different res_model between model?

Tags: odoo-8

```
 <record model="ir.actions.act_window" id="open_gtd_all_tasks_pci">
    <field name="name">Tasks (GTD)</field>
    <field name="res_model">project.task</field>
    <field name="search_view_id" ref="project_gtd.view_task_gtd_search"/>
    <field name="context">{'set_visible': True, 'gtd': True, 'search_default_timebox_id': 1, 'search_default_open': 1, 'search_default_open_project': 1, 'hide_stage': 0}</field>
    <field name="view_type">form</field>
    <field name="view_mode">kanban,tree,form,calendar,gantt,graph</field>
</record>

<record id="planningtask_calendar_view_inherit" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">ic.team.planning.task.calendar.inherit</field>
    <field name="model">ic.team.planning.task</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="ic_project_issue.ic_team_planning_task_calendar_view"/>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <xpath expr="//calendar[@string='Team Planning']" position="attributes">
            <attribute name="mode">week</attribute>
        </xpath>
    </field>
</record>
```

what different res_model with model,what the effect , when use model or res_model? i need explained :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here we have major different between res_model and model,

**For Odoo Action of View:**

**model :**

In model action is important for base record for the database table hear which is used to store the particular action of that record id.

In your example :

`model="ir.actions.act_window"`   **As**  a  **ir_actions_act_window database table**

`id="open_gtd_all_tasks_pci"` **As** a  **unique id for that action table record**

which is used to create a new record with the  id,res_model,search_view_id,context,view_type,view_mode with `ir_actions_act_window database` table

**res_model :**

Action of the particular model

**For Odoo Design of View:**

for  `model="ir.ui.view"`  for the record as ir_ui_view database table to store a new record as `planningtask_calendar_view_inherit` unique id
and same as for name,model,inherit_id fields for storing the record.

hear **model field** is for desgin the view for that particular model (database table).

In generally Odoo(OpenERP) understand **. (dot)** with particular model name and make it as  **_(underscore)** and store that record it as the database table.

**like**  `res.partner` module Odoo (formally OpenERP) treat as `res_partner` database table.

Comment: Yes this helped..Thanks for your respone and details answer ;)